# How can I get VisualElement coordinates on screen iOS Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, coordinates, screen

I need to know VisualElement coordinates in device screen coordinate space on iOS in Xamarin project.

Android has its own method [GetLocationOnScreen](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/android.views.view.getlocationonscreen?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12)

But iOS hasn't

I found this solution:

```
public static Point GetScreenCoords(this VisualElement view)
{
  var result = new Point(view.X, view.Y);

  while (view.Parent is VisualElement parent)
  {
    result = result.Offset(parent.X, parent.Y);
    view = parent;
  }

  return result;
}
```

but properties X ad Y of VisualElement are relatives to parents bounds and don't provide required values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DependencyService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction) to implement the function. I wrote a simple case to get the coordinates of VisualElement. In my simple, I need to get the border of the element relative to the parent element (the child element is inside the parent element). If no parent element is specified, the method returns the bounds of the element relative to the window. You can refer to this:

Create a dependent interface:

```
public interface IMyLocation
{
    RectangleF GetCoordinates(VisualElement element, VisualElement parentElement);
}
```

iOS implementation:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(MyLocation))]
namespace FormsDemoWang.iOS
{
    public class MyLocation : IMyLocation
    {
        public RectangleF GetCoordinates(VisualElement element, VisualElement parentElement)
        {
            IVisualElementRenderer renderer = Platform.GetRenderer(element);
            UIView elementNativeView = renderer.NativeView;
            UIView parentNativeView = null;
            
            if (parentNativeView != null) {
                parentNativeView = Platform.GetRenderer(parentElement).NativeView;
            }

            CGRect rect = elementNativeView.ConvertRectToView(elementNativeView.Frame, parentNativeView);
            float x = (float)Math.Round(rect.X);
            float y = (float)Math.Round(rect.Y);
            float width = (float)Math.Round(rect.Width);
            float height = (float)Math.Round(rect.Height);
            return new RectangleF(x, y, width, height);
        }
    }
}
```

Used in Forms:

```
        var coordinates = DependencyService.Get<IMyLocation>().GetCoordinates(myElement, parentElement);
        var xlable = new Label { Text = $"X:{coordinates.X}" };
        var ylable = new Label { Text = $"Y:{coordinates.Y}" };
```